# changeImage on click, then a link in js?

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript and need a hand...

I've got an image that changes on a click with this:

```
<img alt="" src="header.gif" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"/>
</p>
    <script language="javascript">
      function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "brain.gif") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "brain.gif";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src="brain.gif";
    }
}   </script>
```

But I want a click on brain.gif to link to a div called #two. How do I make that new element a link?

Comment: "Link" to a `div#two` how? Also your `if`/`else` makes no sense and have no effect at all (it does like `if (a==b) { a=b } else { a=b }`).

Comment: Your question is unclear. `What's in div #two? What should appear on screen? Why are all images called brain.gif?` Please rewrite question and state clearly what you need to do. Use step-by-step if possible. I'm sure your question would have been solved by now if it was more clearly stated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly elegant but it's what you want, I believe?  I moved the click handler outside of the HTML and you can do some cleanup like storing imgClickAndChange instead of looking it up each time, but you get the point I'm sure!

HTML:

```
<img alt="" src="header.gif" id="imgClickAndChange" />
```

JavaScript:

```
 function changeImage() {

      if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "brain.gif") {
          document.location.hash = "#something"; // this will jump you down the page to an element with ID of "something"
      } else {
          document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "brain.gif";
      }
  }

  var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
  img.onclick = changeImage;
```

Comment: Great.  Be sure to do the cleanup work.  Wrapping it in an A like the below is fine too but I'm not crazy about listening to a native click and then a JS click inside of that.  There's nothing wrong with that but sometimes order matters and so I just prefer to keep it all in one event.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to wrap your image in anchor tags, that way you can set the `href` of the anchor. Also, you should pass in `this` to your `onclick`

HTML:

```
<a href="#test"><img alt="" src="header.gif" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage(this)"/></a>
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(obj) {
    if (obj.src == "brain.gif") 
    {
        obj.src = "brain.gif";
    }
    else 
    {
       obj.src="brain.gif";
    }

    //Change the href of the anchor
    obj.parentNode.href = "#two";
    console.log(obj.parentNode.href);
}
```